# Filter List in Django JSON Field with string contains

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

My Django JSON field contains a list of values like ["N05BB01", "R06AX33"].

```
atc_code = JSONField(default=list())
```

I would like to filter this field, for 'does any string in list contain "N05"?'.

like

```
mymodel.objects.filter(?????)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case if you are not using `SQLite` or `Oracle`, you can use `contains`:

```
mymodel.objects.filter(atc_code__contains='N05')
```

Which generates this SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM "mymodel" WHERE UPPER("mymodel"."atc_code"::text) LIKE UPPER(%N05%)
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Relational-based answer

Usually, such an approach (with a list of values in JSONField) can be possible when the relational structure is used in the wrong way.

The best approach here:

1. Create a new model that describes your `atc_code` entity. For example `AtcCode`
2. Depends on the meaning of the atc_code and its relation to the `MainEnity` use [ForeignKeyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) or [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField)

Utilize all pros from the relational database and powerful Django ORM with such built-in features as filtering, adding, removing, querying with any database backend.

It will work on any supported database. A relational database will work faster when you are using relations properly.

My recommendation is to use JSONField when you have a really unstructured object.